# SharePoint 2010 SocialDataService - Invalid security validation

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm using javascript to run some web services (SharePoint 2010 SocialDataServices). I've already tested the "CountCommentsOnURL" command without any problems, but when I'm trying to use, for example, the "AddComment" command , I get the following error:

"Server was unable to process request. The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.  The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."

Looking through the Internet, I've seen some articles about turning some security settings off - not an option for me. Obviously, refreshing the page doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following examples demonstrate how to post comments via SocialDataServices service on the client side:

Example 1. Adding comment

```
//url parameter corresponds to Page Url
//comment parameter 
function addComment(url,comment)
{
     var soapEnv =
        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
              <soap:Body>    \
                    <AddComment xmlns='http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/SocialDataService'> \
                                <url>" + url + "</url> \
                                <comment>" + comment + "</comment> \
                                <isHighPriority>false</isHighPriority> \
                                <title></title> \
                     </AddComment> \
              </soap:Body> \
         </soap:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        result: result,
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_vti_bin/SocialDataService.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/SocialDataService/AddComment");
                },
        success: function(data, status, xhr){
           //..
        }
    });
}
```

Example 2. Adding comment using [SPServices library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

```
function addComment(url,comment)
{

   $().SPServices({
        operation: "AddComment",
        url: url,
        title:'',
        comment:comment,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
           console.log($(xData.responseXML));
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
addComment('http://intranet.contoso.com/pages/somenews.aspx','new comment goes here');
```